# Camunda doesnt use MySql as Database

Tags: mysql, wildfly, camunda

I'm setting up a Wildfly 11 Application Server with Camunda BPM 7.9.0.
Deployment works fine. I also deployed the MySql Connector for Java and created a Datasource for my database. However Camunda won't use that Datasource. I have already looked up many tutorial but i have set up correctly according to these.

I have tried to manually add the mysql connector and now I used the deployment method which works fine. I also tried a fresh installation of everything including the OS. I'm on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS ( If that's a problem, which i dont think it is, please tell me). I also deleted the default data source with the result that Camunda cant be deployed anymore, but the Wildfly Servers is online. That showed me that it still connects to the H2 Database.

```
   <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/camunda" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false" statistics-enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/camunda</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>MyUser</user-name>
                    <password>MyPass</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql.driver">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

With this Configuration I expect that it connects to the MySQL Database, but it still used the H2 Database. Is this the only thing i need to do or do i need to edit something in the .war file?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but did you also configure camunda to choose the mysql DB?
The section you copied is just the setup of the datasource (it exists), but you need to go to the section where camunda is told which db to use.

Check out: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/user-guide/runtime-container-integration/jboss/ for examples.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:org.camunda.bpm.jboss:1.1">
    <process-engines>
      <process-engine name="default" default="true">
        <datasource>java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine</datasource> <--- HERE!
        <history-level>full</history-level>
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer!
I have figured out that you need to change it in the ApplicationContext.xml of the camunda.war file.
The value needed to be changed is:

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="java.sql.Driver" />


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
<property name="targetDataSource">
 <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="java.sql.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname" />
  <property name="username" value="user" />
  <property name="password" value="pass" />
</bean>
</property>
```

I hope this helps others!